# How can I show in cart items in my index view?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm working on an ecommerce app, and I have a template that displays all my products.

I want to show how many of the item are in the cart. But I can't seem to figure out how to get that information from my for loop.

I want to check if the current product in my for loop matches with an OrderItem for that user.

I'm able to do this in the detail view but not my catalogue/index

Code:

template

```
{% for product in products %}

{{product.title}} - {{product.quantity_in_cart}}

{% endfor %}
```

(As of right now, product.quantity_in_cart does nothing. I would like it to show how many of this product are in the cart)

view

```
def product_index(request):
title = "My Products"
products = Product.objects.all()
order = get_cart(request)
cart = Order.objects.get(id=order.id, complete=False)
items = cart.orderitem_set.all()
context = {
'title' : title,
'products' : products,
'cart' : cart,
'items': items
}
return render(request, "store/product_index.html", context)
```

models

```
class Order(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
description = RichTextField(blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def product_index(request):

    title = "My Products"
    products = Product.objects.all()
    order = get_cart(request)
    cart = Order.objects.get(id=order.id, complete=False)
    items = cart.orderitem_set.all()

    # Changes
    for product in products:
        qty = 0
        if items.filter(product=product).exists():
            qty = items.get(product=product).quantity
        setattr(product, 'quantity_in_cart', qty)

    context = {
    'title' : title,
    'products' : products,
    'cart' : cart,
    'items': items
    }
    return render(request, "store/product_index.html", context)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly if you change items.get(product=product).qty to items.get(product=product).quantity

Comment: yeah sry i wrote 'qty' field of my own models..
still like what @mohamed-elkalioby said, its not a good aproach but exaclty what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a session key called 'cart' which can be a list and each item in the list can be a dictionary containing 'name', 'quatity' and price, as the the user is adding to the cart you add you the session variable and in the template you can render the cart using a for like this

```
{% for product in request.session.carr%}
 {%endfor%}
```

Comment: I have that actually already, but what I need to do is display all products, and then check for every product if that item is in my current user's cart, and display quantity for the OrderItem rather than the product

Comment: But that will be very slow, why will you do that?

Comment: Items can also be added to cart from the index, I want users to be able to see how many they already have or if the item is in their cart

Comment: That is the idea of session ,ppl can add items from anywhere, all go to the session

Comment: Which is fine, the session already contains the cart data (backed up by the db), the issue was querying if each item in the catalogue was in the current session/user cart. The accepted answer shows a solution for what I was trying to do